# How to modify the JavaScript window object prompt dialog

Tags: javascript

The JavaScript window object provides a prompt dialog to get information from the user, but is not wide enough for my site name, in my case, so the top line is cut off, which looks rather unprofessional:

[image]

I would prefer that the top "The page at ..." line not appear at all.

Is there any way to control this prompt, or at least make it wider so the entire top line can display?

Thanks.

Comment: Simply, You can't

Comment: Just override the `prompt()` function and create your own prompt box.

Comment: make your own custom overlay with a form field instead of using `prompt` or `confirm`

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way to do it. The signature of the prompt method is window.prompt(text, value)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.prompt
A possible solution is to use a dialog component, like the jQueryUI dialog widget.
https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form

Comment: @Rahil: while overriding a function is usually a good solution, overriding the the prompt box would not work without changing the caller, because the native prompt is synchronous, while the custom component should be asynchronous. Moreover, by overriding the window.prompt, the every caller of the window.prompt function would not work anymore.

Comment: @RahilWazir: No, don't override `window.prompt`. You would hardly be able to build a synchronous function for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't. Sorry :-(

This is built in the browser, you can't configure it. It also looks different for every browser, for example in Opera, there's no `The page at' text, and the entire window looks very different.

`prompt()` (& related `confirm()`, `alert()`) are really simple tools, and almost never used in modern web development.

What you can do, however, is duplicate the same functionality with HTML & CSS, there are a number of standard libraries for this, I personally really like Twitter Bootstrap, you could use [a modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals), put an input & `Okay' button in that, and bind an event on the`Okay' button to get the value of the input.
But more work, but looks (& works!) a lot better.
Note that Bootstrap comes with a lot of tools (which is good, IMHO), and is fairly large, it's fairly modular, and you can strip it down though.

For a more simple replacement, you might want to try [alertify.js](http://fabien-d.github.io/alertify.js/). I've never used it, so I can't testify to the quality. It was simple the top result on my search.

Of course, making your own HTML & CSS isn't terribly difficult either.

Answer (score 0):

Carpetsmoker,

Your alertify suggestion turned out to be the answer for me! The simple code below . . .

```
        alertify.set({ buttonReverse: true });  // put OK button on left
        alertify.prompt("Publish as ...", function (e, str) {
                    if (e) {  // OK clicked
                            g.last_publish_name = str;
                            publishPage(str);
                    } 
                }, g.last_publish_name);  // the field default
```

generates the prompt:

[image]

And I have complete control over styling!  What a find!  Thanks!

Comment: Alertify doesn't work at all with Safari so I backed it out. I was using alertify 0.3.11.